# How to move and manage overlapping of x ticks with axis in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot an inlet graph which is shown in Figure. Being an inlet graph it is needed to show x tics and y ticks of relatively big sizes for clear visibility. But when I increase the fonts as,
`set xtics font ", 40"`
tics overlaps with axis. I increased the plot size `set term png size 1000, 1000` but still the issue persists. Kindly suggest if there is a way to move the tics below or to a desired position in graph.

**Edit:**

The gnuplot script looks like this,

```
set term png size 1000, 1000
set output "b_vs_N.png"
set style fill solid
set style circle radius 0.001
FIT_LIMIT=1.e-14


set yrange [0.15:0.25]
set style fill solid
set style circle radius 0.001
set xtics 10
set ytics 0.03

set border 15 back lw 6
set xtics font ", 40"
set ytics font ", 22"
set ylabel "b" enhanced font "1 {,40}"
set xlabel "N_i" font "1 {,40}"
set lmargin 12
set bmargin 4

set palette model HSV 
set palette rgb 3,2,2 
set palette maxcolors 12 
set view map

AA(x)=a+b*x+c*x**2
fit AA(x) "data.txt" using 1:2 via c, b, a

plot "data.txt" using 1:2 lt 1 pt 11 ps 2.0 lc rgb "black" notitle, AA(x) w lines lw 2 lc rgb "sienna1" notitle
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your exact (minimal) code and the full graph such we can easily reproduce your case. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Especially, since you are mentioning that this is an inlet graph. Do you use `multiplot`, etc.? Check `help xtics` and the options there.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. You are explicitly setting `set bmargin 4`. This is probably too small for font size 40 tic labels.

Comment: Yes, also with 'set xtics 10 out font ",40" offset 0,0',,,, changing 0,0 to other values I was able to move fonts along with set bmargin 4 change, I was able to produce the desired plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is uncomplete without code and therefore difficult to reproduce. Please check `help xtics`. There is the option `offset`.

Maybe the following example helps to solve your issue.
In the example below no special offset seems to be necessary, i.e. `offset 0,0`, but you can shift and adjust the labels in x and y direction.

**Code:**

```
### tic label offset
reset session

set multiplot

    plot sin(x)/x
    
    set origin 0.07, 0.6
    set size   0.3,0.3
    set xrange [0:10]
    set xtics 5 out font ",20" offset 0,0
    plot x**2
    
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]